# can't seem to fix PyCharm warnings in a simple PyQt program

Tags: pycharm, pyqt4

The following program (an extract of my real code)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = QtGui.QPushButton("Test")

    def on_pressed():
        print("Pressed")
        QMessageBox.warning(w, 'Info', 'Button Pressed')

    w.pressed.connect(on_pressed)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

triggers the following three warnings in PyCharm (eg when running `Code/Inspect Code...` ) related to the `QMessageBox.warning` call

- > Calling a method by class using an instance of a different class; 
  >   Passing PyQt4.QtGui.QPushButton.QPushButton instead of
  >   PyQt4.QtGui.QMessageBox.QMessageBox. Is this intentional?
- > Incorrect call arguments; Parameter 'QString_1' unfilled
- > Type checker; Expected type 'QMessageBox', got 'QPushButton' instead

and one warning related to the PyQt `connect` call

- > Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function'

Any idea how I can work-around/avoid these warnings?

Comment: According to documentation : https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html, signals and slots are declared at compile-time, I don't know the details of how about PyQt handles this, but PyCharm cannot know about this mechanism and thus throws a warning. Multiple issues have been opened about this in PyCharm issues : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22908 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12498 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4120

Comment: Does anyone have any idea when this problem could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. You're passing the function a QPushButton, in your case the 'w'. The function is expecting a QMessageBox. So just pass it one like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = QtGui.QPushButton("Test")
    dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox()

    def on_pressed():
        print("Pressed")
        QMessageBox.warning(dialog, 'Info', 'Button Pressed', 'Okay')

    w.pressed.connect(on_pressed)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thankf for the suggestion!  Where did you find that it expects a QMessageBox? http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#warning  seems to indicate that a QWidget is sufficient.

Comment: QWidget should be sufficient. This is apparently a bug in PyCharm.