# How to remove Pycharm warnings in simple Pyqt program?

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm learning Pyqt5 for my program, and I have some problems.

I'm using Pycharm, and it shows three warning in my sample code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmXog.png), but it works well. I know nothing about Pyqt yet and this warnings are very annoying.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238014/cant-seem-to-fix-pycharm-warnings-in-a-simple-pyqt-program) Stack Overflow question but I think this is not same situation with me. (Wrong?)

Warning messages are like this:
`Parameter 'flags' unfilled.` (What is flags parameter?)
`Unresolved attribute reference 'connect' for class 'pyqtBoundSignal'`
`Parameter 'p_str_1' unfilled`  (**What is this Thing?**)

How to solve these warnings?
I'm using Pycharm community edition, Python 3.8 and Windows 10.

Comment: Those warnings are that, warnings. Is there a specific reason for which you want to avoid them, or are you just preoccupied that they might be somehow *severe*?

Comment: You may need to install/upgrade [PyQt5-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/).